# shell script executes ok on command line but not from cron job

Tags: shell, cron

I have a very simple one liner update_pot.sh

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext -olocale/messages.pot --from-code=UTF-8 -j
```

it works file if run ./update_pot.sh from prompt.
 but when i call from a cron job it returns

```
xgettext: no input file given
Try `xgettext --help' for more information.
```

I tried putting #! /bin/sh  for the first line but no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably running from the wrong directory.  Put a `cd` to the correct directory at the beginning of the script or change the `find` to use an absolute path.

Comment: You could also change `find .` to `find /path/to/starting/directory`

Comment: yes it was the path.I added a cd $(dirname $0) at the beginning. I purposely left the path . in the find so the the script which is part of a php application will work no matter where the whole directory is copied or moved.

Answer (score 0):

I always try the same command with no environment like

```
env - find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext -olocale/messages.pot --from-code=UTF-8 -j
```

but Cakemox is right - you should specify the path to find